# Is it correct? "in a small hole on one of the Baker Street sidewalks"

Tags: prepositions

I want to say, Ray lived in a small hole. the hole is on a sidewalk. and the sidewalk location is Baker Street.

Is the following correct? are the prepositions (in & on) correct?

> The mouse lived **in a small hole on one of the Baker Street sidewalks**.

I imagine it as something like this

[image: a mouse hole with a green door]

Comment: The preposition is important. If you say *in* it refers to an actual hole dug into a sidewalk. If you say *on* it refers, probably metaphorically, to a dwelling located at an address along the sidewalk. Usually we say holes are dug *into* (or *in*) things.

Comment: Where do you have this hole? Could you mock up an image that would show where the hole is? I'm not sure that either option makes much sense to me in AmE.

Comment: @Catija, take a look at this one: http://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s480x480/e35/14280588_312841969069670_1580047395_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMzNTgxMjQxOTkxNDUwNDM0Mw%3D%3D.2

Comment: I  would say *The mouse lived in a small hole on Baker Street that opened directly onto the  sidewalk.* http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/open-into-onto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *The mouse lived in a small hole on one of the Baker Street sidewalks.*

**Are the prepositions correct?**

Yes, assuming we want to describe his dwelling as a "hole".

We don't know what's behind the door, or how roomy the space is. It may be something just barely big enough for the mouse to sleep in, or it may be something far more spacious. Technically speaking, in the latter case, he doesn't really live in the hole; instead, he goes through the hole to get into his home. But I think the sentence works fine as-is: idiomatically, we can use *in* to describe the place where a critter lives, and *on* to describe an address.

If I was going to reword the sentence, I might do so as follows:

*The mouse lived in a small hole on one of Baker Street's sidewalks*.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are showing a small doorway, one would not usually imagine a "hole" behind it

> The mouse lived **in** a small hole **on** one of the Baker Street sidewalks.

instead possibly

> The mouse lived **in** a small room with an entryway **on** one of the Baker Street sidewalks.
>   The mouse lived **in** a small room with a front door **on** a Baker Street sidewalk.

[image]

Your usage of *in* and *on* are correct. 
Cute picture, looks like a child's story.

Comment: Technically, the [mousehole](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mousehole) is the _entryway_ and not the actual home, but I still disagree with your advice to change _hole_ to _room_.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, at least for the opening sentence, you might describe the mouse's home as "A small (furnished) hole **off of** a Baker Street sidewalk".

But "a small hole" is not very evocative.  I would use more descriptive language.  Consider this description of Bilbo Baggin's "hole" from "The Hobbit":

> "In a hole in the ground there lived a hobbit. Not a nasty, dirty, wet hole, filled with the ends of worms and an oozy smell, nor yet a dry, bare, sandy hole with nothing in it to sit down on or to eat: it was a hobbit-hole, and that means comfort.

There's much more, but you get the idea.  You can start with "a hole" and then elaborate, or indicate (as I did with "furnished") that it is an actual *living space* and not just a wild animal's *den*.